# NetSNMP: snmpset OCTET String Without Hex Type

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, octetstring

I know that it is possible to use snmpset to set a value for an object of HEX STRING type with the 'x' type identifier in the command line.

Is it possible to use snmpset to set the value of an object that is only of type OCTET STRING? The octet string type does not seem to be listed in the snmpset man pages.

Comment: The more you read about SNMP, the better you understand that `OCTET STRING` is just an array of bytes. So you can store quite a few things there and use switches like `-x`, `-s`, and `-b`, depending on the purpose.

Comment: I was asking because I was given a custom MIB where one of the values was defined as a fixed length OCTET STRING and I was scratching my brain on how to set the value with generic tools. I know that SNMP uses BER encoding so it includes a type when it sends a value using snmp set. I didn't know if there was a HEX type or not as compared to an OCTET STRING type so I didn't know if the device would reject the set message or not.

Comment: You can always start with `-s` to see if everything just works. BTW, there is nothing called "HEX STRING" in SNMP types. Don't create unnecessary ambiguity.